# How generate table using data from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to generate a table with varying number of columns? I have an array of my data from php file names res. The res array changes depending on the selection of items in my chechbox. `selected_ids1` is array of my chosen checkboxes. How to generate a table in success function?

```
$.ajax({
      url: "myline.php",
            data: {name: name, Firstdate:$("#date1").val(), Seconddate:$("#date2").val(), myTags: selected_ids},

            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success:  function(result){ 


            var res = $.parseJSON(result);
```

My php file

```
$myTags = $_POST["myTags"];

 $firstdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['Firstdate']));

$seconddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['Seconddate']));

$serverName = "192.168.0.75\SQLEXPRESS"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"SmartNPR", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"aaa-111");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$Mydata = array(); 

$Mydata1 = array(); 

$FullArray = array();

$tag2 = implode(", ", $myTags);

$tag2=preg_replace('/\s+/','', $tag2);

foreach($myTags as $tag){
    $tag=preg_replace('/\s+/','', $tag);

    $handle = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT TS,$tag2 FROM Data WHERE Ts between cast('$firstdate' as DateTime) and cast('$seconddate' as DateTime)"); 

    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($handle)){

    array_push($Mydata, array("date" => $row['TS']->Format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), "$tag" => $row[$tag]));
}

 }
 echo json_encode($Mydata);
```

Comment: post the JSON data

Comment: What is the return data?

Comment: Each row of a table has as many columns as there are cells. There is a concept of [*colgroup*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup), but it can't be used to create columns.

Comment: @jackBashford updated my question

Comment: @AshayMandwarya Updated my question